# mongodb higher faults on Windows than on Linux

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am executing below C# code -

```
for (; ; )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doc# {0}", ctr++); 
    BsonDocument log = new BsonDocument();
    log["type"] = "auth";
    BsonDateTime time = new BsonDateTime(DateTime.Now);
    log["when"] = time;
    log["user"] = "staticString"; 
    BsonBoolean bol = BsonBoolean.False;
    log["res"] = bol;    
    coll.Insert(log);
}
```

When I run it on a MongoDB instance (version 2.0.2) running on virtual 64 bit Linux machine with just 512 MB ram, I get about 5k inserts with 1-2 faults as reported by mongostat after few mins.

When same code is run against a MongoDB instance (version 2.0.2) running on a physical Windows machine with 8  GB of ram, I get 2.5k inserts with about 80 faults as reported by mongostat after few mins.

Why more faults are occurring on Windows? I can see following message in logs- 
[DataFileSync] FlushViewOfFile failed 33 file

Journaling is disable on both instances

Also, is 5k insert on a virtual machine with 1-2 faults a good enough speed? or should I be expecting better inserts?

Comment: If possible, you should add db.<collectionname>.stats(), mongostat, iostat result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1163

Answer (score 1):

page fault counter on Windows is in fact the total page faults which include both hard and soft page fault.

```
Process : Page Faults/sec. This is an indication of the number of page faults that
occurred due to requests from this particular process. Excessive page faults from a    
particular process are an indication usually of bad coding practices. Either the 
functions and DLLs are not organized correctly, or the data set that the application
is using is being called in a less than efficient manner.
```